# Hibernate code generation not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I followed this tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables After I click finish, it looks like something is being executed, but I can't find any classes in output destination, no errors, anything. Am I missing something?

I tried googling a bit, but without any luck. I don't want to do all of it manually. Is there some workaround or other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to anyone facing same problem: try refresh...

Answer (score 0):

There are three pieces involved in Hibernate ORM:

1. Objects
2. Tables in a relational model
3. XML or annotation based mapping from objects to models.

It sounds like you have tables and want to generate objects.  Since annotations are embedded in objects, you can't have those yet.

So - do you have the XML mappings from tables to objects?  If not, this can't work.

If yes, read the messages more closely.  There's a hint buried in the output somewhere.

Comment: I thought it generates mappings as well.

Comment: Gotta have two of the three as far as I know.  In your case, it'd have to have objects whose attributes followed convention with table and column names.  It can follow conventions, but it can't read minds.

Comment: I still don't see why it isn't possible. I just did it using another tool.